# Need help in NSDateFormatter

Tags: date, nsdateformatter

I know this is a simple question, but im dealing with this problem for almost 6 hours. I want to order a date to another format. Not a big deal, but it still gives me back: (null)

*Example:*

**Date I have:**
2013-06-01 10:54:42

**Date I want to be displayed:**
01-06-2013 10:54:42

My code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-06-01 10:54:42";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you running this on the main thread? This code works for me.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's to old and the question is not relevant anymore. Please delete this question. With 112 views in 3 years it will not be missed. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's deprecated and won't help others...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's outdated and doesn't help someone else. Can be removed please!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

You are creating the formatter but not using it to create your date string. Instead you're just printing the date object directly and its description method is printing it out with a default formatting, not the formatter you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine

```
  NSString *dateString = @"2013-06-01 10:54:42";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: OPs code does not. It prints the default formatting, not the formatting OP wants (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss)

Comment: Then that should be your question.Now it says you are getting null

Comment: @Vision It prints the default format because he prints the date." Not a big deal, but it still gives me back: (null)" is never true in the question

Answer (score 1):

Either way it works for me. Must be something in the actual code you have the problem with. The code you show is obviously prepared for this question:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-06-01 10:54:42";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Output:

```
2013-06-01 19:54:19.497 testpgm[23606:c07] 2013-06-01 08:54:42 +0000
2013-06-01 19:54:21.452 testpgm[23606:c07] 01-06-2013 10:54:42
```

Comment: The problem in the OPs code was that OP wasn't using the formatter to format what they were printing, and instead were printing the date object directly.

Comment: Yes, but why does he say he gets (null). I get a standard formatted string which is because NSDate does implement method a description used in such cases.

Comment: I really couldn't say why OP said that